# When using twilio to generate web app to web app voice calls how can I switch to handheld or loudspeaker based on the user selection from client side

Tags: reactjs, twilio, audio-streaming, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

Using ReactJS as the client-side,
Are there any build-in functions in "Twilio.Device" that I can use
there are some function related to audio in Twilio.Device.audio

referred the docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/overview-1x-deprecated/device
but haven't got any exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First, not all browsers support setting the output destination, so be aware of that.

For browsers that do support it, the `device` object has an `audio` property which has an `availableOutputDevices` property that lists the available destinations. There is a vanilla [JS example in the documentation for creating a drop down menu and updating the audio output](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice/device-audio#outputdevicecollection). I recommend you take a look at that and translate it to React.